AdBlock blocks connections to Photon servers
I'm making multiplayer game with Photon Fusion 2 for WebGL platform
And AdBlock blocks connection to Photon servers.
If I turn off adblock for my website, game connecting to servers and everything works fine
Console errors in this case
So what can I do in this situation without telling users to turn off AdBlock?
I didn't really try to do anything. Can not see clear solution myself. Google didn't help. Upgrading to Fusion v2 didn't help.

So what can I do in this situation? -> I guess If I turn off adblock for my website, game connecting to servers and everything works fine ..?

@derHugo tell every user to turn off adblock just to connect is too much

"AdBlock" isn't a homogenous thing that works the same everywhere. Most ad blockers use different filter lists, provided by different entities, and configurable by the user - so first of all I'd check, if this gets blocked due to being on one of the more "common" lists, or perhaps due to something specific you added yourself - if the latter, it might not even affect the majority of your users. But if that is not the case - then your only alternative to asking users to turn off/configure their ad blocker, it to use another service, that doesn't get blocked by major blockers by default.

Solution found!
Inside PhotonAppSettings

Use WSS as protocol
And set fixed region

PhotonAppSettings
